# React App dependency conflict with webpack-server

Tags: reactjs, webpack

> npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use
> `--location=global` instead. npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR!
> webpack-server@"^0.1.2" from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Fix
> the upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR! this command with
> --force, or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. npm ERR! npm ERR! See
> C:\Users\Emre Kızıltoprak\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt
> for a full report.

Package json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.3",
    "webpack-server": "^0.1.2"

  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  }
```

I created a react app without create-react-app. I did my setup manually. Now iam getting a dependency conflict. It is gone when i remove webpack server or with the usage of --legacy-peer-deps. But i do not want to force things. Is there anyone with real solution ?

Comment: What version of react are you using ? And also what version of webpack ? Could you update your question to reveal your package.json.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure which tutorial you are following, but if it is this one: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/create-react-app-without-create-react-app-cra-elhousieny-phd%25E1%25B4%25AC%25E1%25B4%25AE%25E1%25B4%25B0/?trackingId=tP9OVj7YQxCNKYXrT5zD1A%3D%3D

I ran into the same issue, I removed Webpack-server, as most other tutorials do not include it. Since removing it seems to be work.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33180650)